# How to keep the splash screen until iOS app finished loading data

Tags: ios

My iOS app loads data via RestKit on startup. Sometimes it takes time so the main window shows before data is loaded. How to show the splash screen while loading is in progress and show the main window when all data is loaded done?
I can call a method or generate an event when all data is loaded.

Answer (score 6):

You should create ViewController with `ImageView` identically to splash screen, and in `viewDidLoad()` call

```
self.presentViewController(splashScreenVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

When data loaded dismiss splashScreenVC

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: even better, show progress of the loading operation so the user isn't wondering what's going on. either a UIActivityIndicator or better, something with actual % complete.

Comment: Used this approach, thanks. Just want to note that its not easy to create identical to LaunchScreen ImageView because there are several LaunchScreen images for each of the screen resolutions and orientations. Matching it in nib file or storyboard is problematic.

Comment: Use switch for UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height to detect which iPhone is it.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with this, but I will answer in more detail:

```
- (IBAction)goDownload:(id)sender {
    //loading simulation
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Splash"];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Run a background thread
        sleep(10);
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:vc completion:nil];
        });
}
```

Also making the source code: https://yadi.sk/d/W83sU-HrcREpE